# assign a vector with concentrations to a dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I have the following data frame.
[image: start dataframe]

and I have a vector containing concentrations:

```
concentration <- c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10)
```

and what I want to do is: if same = no. fill in the concentrations for that drug. so it will look like this:
[image: end result]

Would there be a way to automate this?

Comment: checkout the 'rep()' function in R

Answer (score 0):

```
df$Concentration = rep(c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10), length.out = nrow(df))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. this would work. But sometimes I would like to add a 7th concentration of a specific drug, and that would offset the concentration range. So I would only like to start the concentration range if same = no. How would you approach that.

Comment: In that case, you should modify your input and expected output with the exceptional concentration in the question description. Also, it will be better to maintain a flag for the exception rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that concentrations start always with the lowest (0.0001) and that any increase is a 10 times higher, you can easily generate it based on the Drug id, without the need of the "same" column.

```
df <- data.frame(Drug = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 7)))

df %>%
  group_by(Drug) %>%
  mutate(Concentration = 0.0001 * 10^(row_number()-1))


    Drug Concentration
   <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1        0.0001
 2     1        0.001 
 3     1        0.01  
 4     1        0.1   
 5     1        1     
 6     1       10     
 7     2        0.0001
 8     2        0.001 
 9     2        0.01  
10     2        0.1   
11     2        1     
12     2       10     
13     2      100
```

Comment: Hi Merijn, Thanks for your answer., yes this would work,. But sometimes I need to add a 7th concentration of a drug (in your example drug 1). and for that drug the concentration must remain NA or blank. If I do it like you stated the concentration of the added drug would become 100. It indeed always starts at 0.0001 but I always want it to 6 concentrations long